# PHP MYSQL event listener

Tags: php, mysql, iframe, listener

I need to build a solution for my supervision page.

I have a system for many users and an office manager, and i created a supervision page in order to supervise the login and status of each user.

When the user log-in to the system, ta row in the DB will be updated. same for his status in the system (Busy, Available, offline...).

What i did that i created an iframe in which am checking those data from DB and refreshing the iframe each 5 seconds in order to check any update.

Is there any solution like listener that allow me to get real time data from DB ? Or when the row in the DB changed, so i get this update in my system ?

Thank you all

Comment: not in basic mysql. triggers can cause things to happen, but there's nothing in mysql that says "on update send http response to X"-type thing.

Comment: Dear @MarcB, is there any solution in server side ?

Comment: An iframe is the worst way to do it, you need to be using AJAX and updating the DOM of the webpage on every update. In fact doing it this way, it's possible to update all employees with just one web call, instead of making one call for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

You can do via many methods, some of which are:

1. take a div instead of your iframe and send AJAX request every 5 seconds and fetch data from database and over write the innerHtml of this div.
2. cache the data and make it dependent on the database operations like insertion, updation or status change. and show the data in the div from the cache
3. the best and simplest way is to use pusher.....it works for push notifications and u can notify do anything once the client is notified

I would recommend using pusher.